# How can I fix Openai and googletrans dependency error

Tags: python-3.x, pip, openai-api, googletrans

googletrans 4.0.0rc1 requires httpx==0.13.3, but you have httpx 0.26.0 which is incompatible.
openai 1.8.0 requires httpx<1,>=0.23.0, but you have httpx 0.13.3 which is incompatible.

I am trying to use both openai and googletrans library in my code but I have this dependency error. How can I fix this.

I try downgrading openai library but the problem is that it doesn't have the function I want in that version. I try upgrading googletrans but it has not been released since 2020.

Comment: you can use subprocess

Comment: can you show me example

Answer (score 1):

```
You can fix this dependency error by using virtual environments.

#create a virtual environment for the first application
subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-m","venv","app1_venv"])
subprocess.run(["source","app1_venv/bin/activate"],shell=True)
subprocess.run(["pip","install","googletrans==4.0.0-rc1","httpx==0.13.3"])

#create a virtual environment for the first application
subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-m","venv","app2_venv"])
subprocess.run(["source","app2_venv/bin/activate"],shell=True)
subprocess.run(["pip","install","openai","httpx==0.27.0"])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).